# Where did Bobby Fischer live in New York?

Tags: fischer

Where did Bobby Fischer live in New York in his younger years? Is anyone able to locate the street address where he lived? Is it 1059 Union Street in Brooklyn from the famous 1951 Helms letter to his mother?

Comment: I think this is on topic. From the [help centre](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions that have to do primarily with chess in its standard form are on-topic here. This includes questions about theory, rules, specific positions/games (including puzzles), chess-specific events, **chess players**, hard facts such as statistics and other historical data, and physical items such as chessboards, pieces, and clocks."_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 1955, his address was 560 Lincoln Place, Brooklyn.  Source:

http://tartajubow.blogspot.com/2015/09/bobby-fischer-lived-here.html

Answer (score 6):

Bobby Fischer lived [here](https://youtu.be/ChAIkCKo3Xo) at Lincoln Place 560 in Brooklyn. The video shows the inside of the building. I was there in September, 2019.

Comment: Very interesting and fascinating footage. It's an old building indeed, and I can only wonder how it was in the 1950s / 1960s. Now it would be great to know in which door / apartment Bobby actually lived, but I feel we'll never know for sure, unless someone who knew him well at those days, shows up.

Comment: @A.N.Other: If it is to be believed, the page linked to in [Scott's answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/19700/224), says the Fischers lived in apartment Q.

Comment: Sure, and since the source seems to be Frank Brady, who knew Bobby well, it should be reliable.